# Calculate difference of two values in H:i:s Format

Tags: php

I have two values in the format H:i:s stored in a variable. I get the fields from a form field in wordpress. The values are the starttime and the endtime. What i need is the difference of these two fields stored in a variable also in H:i:s format. How is this possible?

My variables:

```
$starttime      = get_field('contest_starttime', $post_id);
$endtime        = get_field('contest_endtime',$post_id);
```

Comment: The format is H:i:s

Comment: you should definitely have tried something. a very naive way would have been to use math, convert these to seconds, substract and convert back to H:i:s. Did you even try anything?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to convert them to `\DateTimeImmutable` then calculate the difference,  as a `\DateInterval` then format that interval, like this:

```
$start = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '10:20:30');
$end = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '5:10:20');

$diff = $end->diff($start);

var_dump($diff->format('%H:%i:%s'));
```

will print:

```
string(8) "05:10:10"
```

see live [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9295ae2da8bba1a797236c61705bffea8fa801b2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) for this

Comment: indeed, they can :) however you should improve your answer to actually show *how* they can do it!